# How to add button inside listbox and do some action

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

i am working on listbox using angualrjs.

```
 <select size="10" id="myselection" ng-model="currentItems" ng-options="s.id as s.text for  s in roles"  ng-change="getCategory(currentItems)"></select>
```

but i dont know how to add button inside listbox and perform some action after click of add button.

Comment: Why do you need button inside `<option/>`?

Comment: You cant. But you can handle the `change` and `click` events to perform some action

Comment: yes ..but we can achieve using directive?but i dont know how to work with directive..:(

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use some component library for example Angular-UI/Bootstrap, which provides nice pack of bootstrap components.

Dropdown is probably what you want to use.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown

It looks like select which contains ordinary links where you can use ng-click.